# Session using CodeIgniter does not seem to work

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

here is my sign in code.

```
  //check if username and password is correct
                    $usr_result = $this->signin_model->get_user($username, $password);
                    if ($usr_result > 0) //active user record is present
                    {
                         //set the session variables
                         $sessiondata = array(
                              'username' => $username,
                              'loginuser' => TRUE
                         );
                         $this->session->set_userdata('logged_in', $sessiondata);
                         redirect("application");
                    }
                    else
```

Here is my logout code.

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Logout extends CI_Controller {

     public function __construct()
     {
          parent::__construct();

          $this->output->set_header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, no-transform, max-age=0, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
    $this->output->set_header("Pragma: no-cache");
    $this->load->library('session');
     }

      function index()
         {
         $this->session->unset_userdata('logged_in');
         $this->session->sess_destroy();
         redirect('signin', 'refresh');

         }
```

Here is my controller

```
public function __construct()
     {
           parent::__construct();
               $this->load->library('session');

                $this->output->set_header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, no-transform, max-age=0, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
        $this->output->set_header("Pragma: no-cache"); 

         if($this->session->userdata('logged_in'))
           {
               $session_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
               $this->load->helper('form');
                   $this->load->helper('url');
                   $this->load->helper('html');
                   $this->load->database();
                   $this->load->library('form_validation');
               $this->load->library('javascript'); 
               $this->load->library('javascript/jquery');
               $this->load->model('chan_model');
           }
           else
           {
             //If no session, redirect to login page
             echo "Chnnlll";
             exit;
             redirect('signin', 'refresh');
           }
     }
```

Now, issue is that, I'm creating session when i login, but then destroy it when I logout, I also have tried to clear cache as well in my all controller files, however it doesn't seem to work. I have been testing it for quite a while now but m not sure what seems to be the issue.

Although my logout code is fine, but some how it allows me to access the controller page again, however it shouldn't, I thought it might be some cache issue, but now m clearing that as well.

Please let me know which is the point where i'm going wrong.

Comment: What version of codeigniter you using?

Comment: my current version is 2.2.2

Comment: First couple things, **I would autoload database and sessions libraries** Make sure you have sessions set up in your database if using codeigniter 2 + http://www.codeigniter.com/docs and http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/libraries/sessions.html

Comment: so you are suggesting to use database to handle sessions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
    //set session user
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    $usr_result = $this->signin_model->get_user($username, $password);

    if(!empty($usr_result)) //active user record is present
    {
        //set the session variables
        $sessiondata = array(
            'username' => $username,
            'logged_in' => TRUE
        );
        $this->session->set_userdata($sessiondata);//alter this line
        redirect("application");
    }
    else
    {

    }
```

each and every controller **before log**, check whether **session user set or not**

> in every controller paste this

**In controller**

```
    $result = $this->signin_model->log_in();
    if($result==true)
    {
        //if TRUE only allow user to access page
    }
    else
    {
        //redirect to Logging page
    }
```

**In model**

```
public function log_in()
{
    $log = $this->session->all_userdata();

    if (isset($log['username'])) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

[Ci Session Helper](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html)

Comment: whats wrong with my line? i mean how will this help? i have tried this one before. what do you have in mind that what should happen by changing this?